# Beta-function for mass

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, field-theory, renormalization

I'm trying to find the renormalization group fixed points for a free, massive, scalar theory
\begin{equation}
S = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx \left( \frac{(\partial_\mu\phi)^2}{2} + \frac{m^2\phi^2}{2} \right)  \ .
\end{equation}
That is, I'll treat $m^2$ as a quadratic interaction, and want to find its corresponding $\beta$-function, $\beta_{m^2}$. I know it's supposed to be
\begin{equation}
\beta_{m^2} = -2m^2 \ ,
\end{equation}
which gives me the fixed point
\begin{equation}
\beta_{m^2} = 0 \quad\Rightarrow\quad m^2 = 0 \ .
\end{equation}
However, how do I find $\beta_{m^2}$? Should I do Feynman diagrams for the two-point function $\langle\phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle$? Can I find it from the path integral? Is it possible to find it from the Callan-Symanzik equation?

Since the free theory is Gaussian, I should not need to do perturbation theory, and be able to solve the theory (find $\beta_{m^2}$) exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that a long calculation is not necessary. But I can also see how some introductions to renormalization would gloss over the physics of it, leaving people with the impression that it's merely some technical tool for Feynman diagrams.

In this case, I would write your action with a bare mass
\begin{equation}
S = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}d^dx \left( \frac{(\partial_\mu\phi)^2}{2} + \frac{m_0^2\phi^2}{2} \right)
\end{equation}
and define a renormalized mass by
\begin{equation}
m_0^2 = \mu^2 m^2
\end{equation}
in order to get something dimensionless. We then arrange for $m$ to run in such a way that $m_0$ is independent of the renormalization scale.
\begin{align}
& \mu \frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} (\mu^2 m^2) = 0 \\
& 2\mu^2 m^2 + \mu^3 \frac{\partial m^2}{\partial \mu} = 0 \\
& \mu \frac{\partial m^2}{\partial \mu} = -2m^2
\end{align}
As expected, this beta function has only a classical term. It's the one we would've guessed by seeing that $\mu$ appeared with an exponent of $2$ in the definition of the renormalized quantity. In an interacting theory, a shift in dimension by $2$ would only be part of the story because there would be further *anomalous* shifts in the dimensions from the loop corrections. This is what quantum terms in the beta function (which some sources misleadingly refer to as the whole beta function) represent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking along the same lines at some point, but afterwards I got confused about $m_0^2 = \mu^2m^2$. Since the renormalization scale $\mu$ have mass dimension one, doesn't this mean that the renormalized mass $m^2$ is dimensionless?

Comment: Yes which is what you want. Perturbative RG tracks the evolution of a coupling constant that you would use in a Taylor expansion, i.e. a dimensionless one.

Comment: This is the same reason why you set $g_0 = \mu^\epsilon Z_g g$ in $\phi^4$ theory. In four dimensions, $g$ and $g_0$ are both dimensionless but in $d = 4 - \epsilon$ only one of them is.

Comment: I see, thanks! I thought it was different for masses.

Now, say I would like to generalize this a bit, e.g. by considering the theory near a boundary
\begin{equation}
S = \int_{\mathbb{R}_+^d}d^dx \left( \frac{(\partial_\mu\phi)^2}{2} + \frac{m_0^2\phi^2}{2} \right) + \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d - 1}}d^{d - 1}x_\parallel \frac{\mu_0^2\hat{\phi}^2}{2} \ ,
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{R}_+^d = \{ (x_\parallel, x_\perp): x_\parallel \in \mathbb{R}^{d - 1}, x_\perp > 0 \}$, and $\hat{\phi}$ denotes the boundary limit of $\phi$.

Comment: Then the $\beta$-function corresponding to the boundary mass $\mu_0$ should have fixed points at $\mu = 0$ (Neumann b.c.'s) and $\mu \rightarrow \pm\infty$ (Dirichlet b.c.'s). It seems like running the same arguments as you did for the bulk mass I only pick up the $\mu = 0$ fixed point.

Comment: That's like asking why an $m = \infty$ fixed point for the empty theory doesn't show up in the bulk beta function. This is a perfectly good fixed point the IR just like $m = 0$ is a fixed point in the UV. The issue then is that we divided both sides of the above equation by $\mu$ which is going to zero.

Comment: Generally, beta functions become unreliable when the energy becomes smaller than a mass threshold. This is why there are different QCD beta functions for each number of "active quarks". Except in the interacting case, there is usually no "division by zero" that raises the red flag. Rather, it's a large log in some Feynman diagram.